# How can I interpret << and | in C

Tags: c

I need help to understand what is happening in this declaration:

```
#define LDA(m)  (LDA_OP << 5 | ((m) & 0x001f))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`y << x` is a [left shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work) of `y` by `x`.
`x & y` is a [bitwise and](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bitwise_operators.htm) of `x` and `y`.

Comment: Thank you, how can I understand what a left shit / bitwise does and purpose?

Comment: @RicardoMustra Click on the links

Answer (score 0):

So, the left shift operator is like multiplying by 10 in base 10, but instead you multiply for 2 in base 2, for example:

In base 10

300 * 10 = 3000

In base 2:

0b0001 * 2 = 0b0010 = 0b0001 << 1

with a << b you "push" the number a, b places to the left.

and the or operator ( | )
you have to take two bits and if one or both of them are true (1) then the result is true.

For example:

0b0010 | 0b0001 = 0b0011

0b0010 | 0b0010 = 0b0010

If you have problems with this operators, just try to work the same numbers but in binary.

Comment: It still does not make sense to me, maybe because I also dont understand the OR bitwise operator?

Comment: I know I have an hexadecimal value, but what am I doing to that value with the 5 |

Comment: And then why do I "multiply it by 2" / shift left to LDA_OP ?

Comment: Left shift is not the same as multiplying by 2 in base 2, because if the value goes over the number that can be contained by the number of bits in the variable, it will truncate the bits shifted over that

Comment: Yes, you are right, but at least is a good base for starting to understand it.